# How to submit an input form by pressing Enter BUT not submit it when shift and enter are pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am creating a script that will enable me to submit a form by pressing the Enter key but i do not want it to submit the form when i press Shift+Enter. Rather when i press Shift + Enter i would like the input to expand just like on Facebook comment.

So far I was able to get the form to submit by pressing enter with this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#comment').keyup(function(e)
    {
        if(e.keyCode == 13)
        {
        var comment = $('#comment').val()
        var sid = $('#sid').val()
            if(comment == "")
            {
                /*alert("Please write something in comment.");*/
            }
            else
            {
                $("#commentbox").append("<div class='commentarea'>"+comment+"</div>");
                $.post("index.php", {sid:sid,comment:comment},function(data)
                {

                })
                $('#comment').val("");
            }
        }
    });            
});
</script>
```

**Problem and Question**
With this code, when i press `Shift and Enter`, apparently `Jquery` recognize it as `Enter` instead of `Shift and Enter`, therefore it validates the form .

**How to make jquery differentiate between `Shift + Enter` from `Enter` , How to make jquery submit the form only when `Enter` alone is pressed ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can catch the shift key with `event.shiftKey`

```
$('#comment').keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 13 && e.shiftKey) {
         // do stuff
    }
...
```